# Is there a way to simplify converting an Option into a Result without a macro?

Tags: rust

I have something like this (the real function is `Ini::Section::get` from [rust-ini](https://github.com/zonyitoo/rust-ini)):

```
impl Foo {
    pub fn get<K>(&'a mut self, key: &K) -> Option<&'a str>
    where
        K: Hash + Eq,
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I have to call it several times:

```
fn new() -> Result<Boo, String> {
    let item1 = match section.get("item1") {
        None => return Result::Err("no item1".to_string()),
        Some(v) => v,
    };
    let item2 = match section.get("item2") {
        None => return Result::Err("no item2".to_string()),
        Some(v) => v,
    };
}
```

To remove code bloat, I can write a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! try_ini_get {
    ($e:expr) => {
        match $e {
            Some(s) => Ok(s),
            None => Err("no ini item".to_string()),
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to remove the code duplication without this macro implementation?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The [`ok_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or) and [`ok_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.ok_or_else) methods convert `Option`s to `Result`s, and the `?` operator automates the boilerplate associated with early `Err` returns.

You could do something like:

```
fn new() -> Result<Boo, String> {
    let item1 = section.get("item1").ok_or("no item1")?;
    let item2 = section.get("item2").ok_or("no item2")?;
    // whatever processing...
    Ok(final_result)
}
```

Comment: The difference between `ok_or` and `ok_or_else`: "Arguments passed to `ok_or` are eagerly evaluated; if you are passing the result of a function call, it is recommended to use `ok_or_else`, which is lazily evaluated."

Comment: @MakotoE: Sure. I only used `ok_or()` because the passed argument is a constant.

Answer (score 46):

If you're using the crate `anyhow` you can import the [`anyhow::Context`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.51/anyhow/trait.Context.html) trait which adds the `.context` method on `Option`s to turn them into `anyhow::Result`s:

```
use anyhow::{Result, Context};

fn new() -> Result<Boo> {
    let item1 = section.get("item1").context("no item1")?;
    let item2 = section.get("item2").context("no item2")?;
    // whatever processing...
    Ok(final_result)
}
```

Comment: This solved casting Option to Result if Option is None for me. I can now have None as a propagated error condition in my function that returns Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>

thanks

Comment: I haven't used Rust in a while. If this answer reflects current best practices, then it should be marked as accepted instead of mine.

Comment: A simple dependency-free solution will always be the best practice IMHO, the accepted answer is good.

Comment: @joseLuís Right, but this is a really good option if you already have a dependency on `anyhow`.